# How to keep my modified version of a project updated?

Tags: git

I've bought a Unity Asset and it comes in form of source codes and I've changed it to meet my needs better.

My problem is that I need to be able to get the future releases and merge it with my own modified version.

I'm using my own modified version in Git, and was wondering whether if there's any way to get the new modifications without need to manually deal with merges, hunks, and other related stuff.

I've read about fork but not sure if I can use it here.

Comment: Just to rephrase your question a bit: You want to have your version of some 'sourcecode' but want to merge new versions of the 'old' sourcecode to automatically merge into your sourcecode without user intervention?

Comment: You could import the sources and all future versions as separate branches. Then you create your own personal feature branch based on the initial version. For every new version you import as branch you now do a rebase of your personal feature branch on the new version branch. You obviously may have to adapt it for that if your modifications do not fit the new version. That way you can always semi-automatically apply your changes to new versions.

Comment: If you want to modify the original source code, you have to expect conflicts when the original source code is updated and you want to pull in those changes. That’s just how it works and there is no way around it; you can be lucky that Git automatically resolves most conflicts, but the chance is still there.

Comment: If  you've made a change to a line, and the upstream project has made a different change to the same line, what would you like git to do?

Comment: @jthill I'm currently copied the section I want to change, comment the original, and edit the copy and I think I want the update to be applied to the commented section. And if there is a new section, like a new method call, added, it should get added as well.

Comment: You're in custom-merge-driver territory.  Git's automerge works on text lines and only knows how to match up change hunks and look for overlaps. Anything beyond that is going to produce lots of wrong merges in other people's code,  no matter how well it works on yours.

Comment: by the way,  the comment-the-original-and-add-the-modified thing isn't necessary any more.  Make the change, commit it with a good message. Git's your engineering log. `git log -- $path` shows which commits affected what you're looking at, add the `--patch` option and it'll show the changes each made, `git blame $path` skips the diffs and shows line by line where each came from.   The code in each commit can be the exact code that's relevant for for that version, no need to gum up the works with outdated hunks when they're in the version where they mattered and finding them is drop-dead easy.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to *simulate* a remote repository with the original code versions.

In order to do that, extract a copy of the source code you received, `cd` to that directory and `git init` it. You'll have a fresh new repo.

Without touching (ie, compiling) anything, run `git checkout --branch upstream` to create a new branch and `git add .` to add all the code to the index. Then `git commit` it, writing  some message saying that's the original source code you received, and include it's version if it has any.

After this, `git checkout --branch master` for creating `master` branch, and do your modifications there. Make as many commits as you need/want - that'd be **your** working branch.

Whenever you get new versions of the third-party code, `git stash` any non-commited changes you have, and then `git checkout upstream` to go back to the latest release you had. Copy all the files you received there - I'd try to `git rm` every file in the repo first, and then copy and `git add` the new files, in case they've removed anyone - and then `git commit` the new version. Once this is updated, `git checkout master` and `git merge upstream` so you include all the changes on your working branch.

You should `git merge` or `git rebase` any other branch you may be working on to include those updates. Also, you may want to do the merge (or a `rebase`) with the updated `upstream` branch in a separate branch so you can test your project in case the update broke any of your changes.

But the key idea is that: have a branch that acts as if the source code was git-versioned, and base your work on that.

Comment: Thanks. I've read and re-read your post but can't understand how my edits on my branch will overload the new modifications that I will get via updated original code base via new files.

Comment: Problem is, that my modification of that code repo is part of another project and I don't know if I can have a code as part of two repositories, one with this one you suggested and one with my project.

Image that it's a middle-ware that I use for my project but the author of that middle-ware updates the code but I had to do changes to it to meet my needs.